# diff program gives false positive for files with non-ASCII characters in filename

Tags: macos, diff

Example:

```
% diff "/Volumes/New Volume/4kyoutube/" "/Volumes/New Volume/tmpmusic"| grep Distortion
Only in /Volumes/New Volume/tmpmusic: ZAC & Bäkka - Distortion (Original Mix) [Sprout].mp3
Only in /Volumes/New Volume/4kyoutube/: ZAC & Bäkka - Distortion (Original Mix) [Sprout].mp3

% diff "/Volumes/New Volume/tmpmusic/ZAC & Bäkka - Distortion (Original Mix) [Sprout].mp3" "/Volumes/New Volume/4kyoutube/ZAC & Bäkka - Distortion (Original Mix) [Sprout].mp3" 
%
```

What can I do about it? The files are identical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a "diff false positive", but rather the two file names are seen as *different*.

My wild hypothesis is that either the two folders are on different devices, with a different file encoding; or that **the two names are encoded differently** albeit they are visually identical. Specifically, one of the two "Bäkka"s is in "precomposed" form, i.e. U+00E4 (UTF-8 C3 A4) while the other is in "decomposed" form, U+0061 U+0308 (UTF-8 0x61 0xCC 0x88) with combination diaeresis.

I have not a MacOS at hand, but I can reproduce this on an ext4 Linux:

```
$ A=$( echo -e "Ba\xcc\x88kka" )
$ B=$( echo -e "B\xc3\xa4kka" )
$ echo $A $B
Bäkka Bäkka
$ touch $A $B
$ ls -la | grep kka
-rw-rw-rw-+  1 lserni  users     0 Apr 29 18:14 Bäkka
-rw-rw-rw-+  1 lserni  users     0 Apr 29 18:14 Bäkka
```

Apparently, *I now have two files with the same name in the same folder*.

I cannot obviously be sure, but you might be in the same straits.

To check, simply run the output of "diff" through `hexdump -C` and see if you have something like,

```
00000020  20 20 20 30 20 41 70 72  20 32 39 20 31 38 3a 31  |   0 Apr 29 18:1|
00000030  36 20 42 61 cc 88 6b 6b  61 0a 2d 72 77 2d 72 77  |6 Ba..kka.-rw-rw|
00000060  70 72 20 32 39 20 31 38  3a 31 36 20 42 c3 a4 6b  |pr 29 18:16 B..k|
00000070  6b 61 0a                                          |ka.|
```

Note that in the hex dump they are immediately visible as "Ba..kka" (the "a" is a normal "a", followed by the UTF8 "add a diaeresis") and "B..kka" (there is only one symbol and it is "small latin a with diaeresis").

## Fixing things

Frankly, I'd run first a normalization on the whole folder structure. Even if you have identically named files, but with a different encoding (i.e. some precomposed, some decomposed), this is going to bite you sooner or later.

From a file system point of view, which system you use is largely irrelevant. The important thing is how you feed the system now and how you use the system now.

If the new incoming files have precomposed names, it makes sense to set all the FS to precomposed (or vice versa), so the standard will be maintained. On the other hand, you might also want to check out functions like searching for files, sorting, and so on, to verify that the files are where you expect them to be (needless to say, *some* systems consider "a", "ä" and "ä" the same, some others don't - they might set "a" and "ä" together, "ä" somewhere else; or vice versa).

I'd try copying a small mp3 file with the names "älpha composed", "älpha decomposed" and "alpha neutral", then working with a folder with those three files as well as "alpha 0 test" and "alpha z test", and then whether decomposed or precomposed is best, if any.

The docs seem to indicate **you should go with decomposed**.

So first thing, you need a list of all the file names. This is easy

```
find . -type f > list-as-it-is.txt
```

But now you need to convert the precomposed elements in the list to their decomposed form. I have done a bit of research and, to add a further layer of complication, it seems that [MacOS and Linux behave differently](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1173/_index.html), and MacOS has several legacy accommodation problems:

> Important: The terms used in this Q&A, precomposed and decomposed,
> roughly correspond to Unicode Normal Forms C and D, respectively.
> However, most volume formats do not follow the exact specification for
> these normal forms. For example, HFS Plus (Mac OS Extended) uses a
> variant of Normal Form D in which U+2000 through U+2FFF, U+F900
> through U+FAFF, and U+2F800 through U+2FAFF are not decomposed (this
> avoids problems with round trip conversions from old Mac text
> encodings). It's likely that your volume format has similar oddities.

In theory you should have only one form on disk ("Mac OS X's BSD layer uses **canonically decomposed UTF-8 encoding** for filenames"). In practice, [it seems to depend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484369/why-does-the-c-runtime-on-mac-os-allow-both-precomposed-and-decomposed-utf-8) (obviously, otherwise you wouldn't have problems; predictably, [you are not alone](https://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/HdH1DPrE/on-macosx-and-files-with-decomposed-utf-8-file-names)).

So, I'm pretty chary about suggesting a conversion method without being able to test it beforehand on a real MacOS. If the files are few, then I'd suggest fixing them by hand - delete one file, copy the other on the other folder.

*In theory*, you could do something like (in Bash)

```
hexa=$( echo -n "$name" | xxd -ps | tr -d "\n" )
if [ $[ 2*${#name} ] -lt ${#hexa} ]; then
    # Not ASCII.
```

or
if ( echo "$name" | file - | grep "UTF-8" > /dev/null ); then

and if the test matches, you can do

```
mv "$name" "$(dirname "$name")/tmpname" && mv "$(dirname "$name")/tmpname" "$name"
```

and *maybe* the first "mv" will recognize the file whatever its encoding, while the second will recreate the name using the fixed default system encoding, which *hopefully* will suit you.

This kind of operation would be very fast, even if it needlessly processes *all* UTF-8 names.

## Ignoring things

You could *ignore* all files with this kind of trick. Then, trouble would arise only when **two files are different, and have differently encoded same name**. Is this an issue? *If* it is not, then you're all set.

Just do a preliminary `grep` to remove the lines containing "^Only":

```
diff ... | grep -v ^Only | grep Distortion
```

## Removing duplicates

This, luckily, bypasses encoding entirely. There are tools that do this already (`jdupes` is the one I use). Files with identical content that differ by MP3 tags will not work with this approach, and you'll probably find [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/248495/how-to-compare-mp3-flac-audio-data-in-a-file-ignoring-header-data-id3-tag-et) useful.

```
find folder1 -type f -exec md5sum \{\} \; | sort > folder1.txt
find folder2 -type f -exec md5sum \{\} \; | sort > folder2.txt
```

Now if you want to get duplicates:

```
join -o 2.2 folder1.txt folder2.txt
```

will get you the files in folder2 that are duplicates (-o 2.1 will get you the files in folder1).

Comment: Nice! `od -c` might be a better alternative to `hexdump -C` or, at least, easier to understand for people who are not used to hex.

Comment: Yes your answer likely answers the question "Why is this happening to me?" while the question being asked was "What can be done about it?", even if the files have different encoding, it isn't what appears from diff if I don't investigate encodings, and if I just want to see if the files are different in the meaning of how the files appear from diff and towards me and application.

Comment: Obviously the output is inconsistent because if diff finds that the files are different then there would not be empty output from `diff "/Volumes/New Volume/tmpmusic/ZAC & Bäkka - Distortion (Original Mix) [Sprout].mp3" "/Volumes/New Volume/4kyoutube/ZAC & Bäkka - Distortion (Original Mix) [Sprout].mp3`

Comment: @terdon I didn't expect it to behave completely different. The filename is completely irrelevant

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz what happens is that `diff` finds what it thinks are *two files with different names*, just as if they were `dir1/apple` and `dir2/pear`. In these cases, diff will **do no compare at all** between the two files; it will instead report that `apple` is not present in dir2, and `pear` is not present in dir1. And this is the output that you do see.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz consider running `convmv` with `--nfc/--nfd` on both folders before diff https://gist.github.com/JamesChevalier/8448512

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz yes, sorry, my previous comment was flat out wrong (so I deleted it). `diff` on directories will compare the file contents when the file names are the same, it just doesn't compare if the file names are different (since that already means the files are different). My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Now that @LSerni has uncovered the issue of **what's** going on, you still need to deal with **how** to work round it.

Clearly some canonical or at least consistent rename is best. But you may be unable to, or it may happen with new files. So we need an enhanced workaround.

What I'd do is avoid the thorny Unicode issue entirely.

I'd run the entire directory through sha512() or some other hashing function (recursive if necessary). Then, I'd use that to recognise files with the same content even if the names differ.  In effect either creating artificially for diff purposes, a canonical filename equivalent (via symlinks  or a programmatic array of paths/hashes), or filtering the output of diff, or running diff in multi passes, or substituting your own logic for reporting uncertain file equivalence but beforehand matching by hash to suggest equivalents.....

In other words, there's a number of ways to do that, and it should be dead easy... but I can't suggest which way works for you, as its not clear your precise goal in diffing them, nor your coding skill.

Comment: My goal is to remove duplicates. In this case I just wanted to verify that directory A has no file that isn't in directory B. I think it can be done if I check the files one by one from an input file that is a list of the filenames. That way I won't have to rename the files, and I could use `cmp` instead for the comparison (with input via `xargs`e.g. `cmp xargs < inputfile` where I first created the `inputfile` where every line is for example `/home/A/bäkkü.mp3  /home/B/bäkkü.mp3` then if the output if empty I've proven that all the files are duplicates. Do you agree?

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz: Comparing files by content is effective at finding different-named copies of the same file, if that's the situation you have.  Get a program that can do that for you, like `fslint` or any other duplicate file finder.  (They'll check size first, not blindly `cmp` every pair.  Maybe even hash files that have any size matches and compare hashes like this answer suggests, to avoid pairwise for large sets of same size).  But if it's only names with different tags / audio quality or any other difference in bytes in the file, then yeah you're stuck trying to canonicalize names.

Comment: Depending how many files there are, either hash all, or compare file sizes+sort, and hash only files with a non-unique size. Then in either case where multiple files have the same hash, delete all but one of them. Done. That removes dups very efficiently in a dir. To compare the two, hash all files in A and all files in B. For each list, `sort` the list and run through `uniq` to keep a single entry for each unique file in A and B. `diff` the 2 lists (as text files) to find what hashes are missing. Refer back to your original lists for a sample file for each of those hashes, to plug the gaps.

Comment: Totally avoids the file names,or filename Unicode issues. Note,does not avoid Unicode issues *within * the files..........

Comment: A possibility is to store into some database some hash of files. See https://www.softwareheritage.org/ for more. They do that, and can detected unique contents in file named very differently